# What is the reason to have a minimum default value for the "executionTimeout" attribute?

Tags: document-library, file-upload, file

If SharePoint Upload time limit can be increased as we wish, why the default is not set to be Max? What is the reason to have a minimum default value for the attribute "executionTimeout"?

```
<location path="upload.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="XXX" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Is it recommended to increase as we wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28vs.90%29.aspx) property `maxRequestLength`

> Specifies the limit for the input stream buffering threshold, in KB.
>   This limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are
>   caused, for example, by users posting large files to the server.

By default for SharePoint 2010 it value is set to 50 MB:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

According to [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which describes software boundaries and limits of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010:

> Upload file size could be increased up to 2047 MB, however a large
>   volume of very large files can affect farm performance

### Execution Timeout

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28vs.90%29.aspx) the `executionTimeout` is a TimeSpan attribute that

> specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to
>   execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET

In SharePoint 2010 by default it value is set to 1 hour.

It value should be increased in case if "Request Timed Out" error occurs

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
```

,otherwise there is no need to modify it value.

Comment: Thanks..Shall we change value of 'executionTimeout' and what are all consequences of this change?

Comment: @Karthikeyan, please verify answer, information about Execution Timeout has been added.

Comment: Thanks for your help...can you also share me the impact on increasing the Execution Timeout value to 1.5hrs?